# Average Energy in generic radial potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Given a particle of mass $m$ moving in the radial potential $$ V(r)=-\frac{\lambda}{r^s} \quad, \ 
\lambda>0$$
I'm asked to compute the $L$-dependence (sign included) of the average kinetic, potential  and total energy on a trial normalizable wave function of the form $$\psi(r)=N\phi(\frac{r}{L})\, ,$$ where $L$ is some positive reference scale, with 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{r \to 0} r\frac{d\psi}{dr}=\lim_{r \to 0} r\frac{d\psi}{dr}=0 
\tag{1}
\end{equation} 
Then verify the result by comparing it with an estimate obtained by using dimensional analysis and the uncertainty principle.

EDIT
For what concern the first point, I think I need to make a reasonable ansatz on the explicit form of the trial wave function. Therefore it could be useful find the asymptotic behavior of the wave function for $r\to 0$ and $r\to \infty$. Assuming for now $0<s<2$ and using the property $(1)$, near the origin we have the usual $\psi\sim r^{l+1}$,  while for large $r$ I have to solve
$$ r^2\frac{d^2\psi}{dr^2}=E\psi$$
I cannot expand $\psi$ in power series, and more importantly I should avoid divergent solutions. so how solve this diff. eq? Is there a fancier way to solve the problem?